# how to select two nodes (pairs of nodes) randomly from a graph that are NOT connected, Python, networkx

Tags: python, nodes, networkx

I want to extract two nodes from a graph, the catch being that they shouldnt be connected i.e. no direct edge exists between them. i know i can get random edges using "random.choice(g.edges())" but this would give me random nodes that are connected. I want pairs of nodes that are NOT connected (a pair of unconnected edges). help me out guys...thanx

Comment: The Graph is connected but the pairs of nodes that i want...they should'nt be connected.

Answer (score 11):

Simple! :)

Grab a random node - then pick a random node from the list of nodes excluding neighbours and itself. Code to illustrate is below. :)

```
import networkx as nx
from random import choice

# Consider this graph
#
#     3
#     |
# 2 - 1 - 5 - 6
#     | 
#     4

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
g.add_edge(1,3)
g.add_edge(1,4)
g.add_edge(1,5)
g.add_edge(5,6)

first_node = choice(g.nodes())                  # pick a random node
possible_nodes = set(g.nodes())
neighbours = g.neighbors(first_node) + [first_node]
possible_nodes.difference_update(neighbours)    # remove the first node and all its neighbours from the candidates
second_node = choice(list(possible_nodes))      # pick second node      

print first_node, second_node
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions proposed here so far will sample the non-edges (v1,v2) uniformly. Consider the example graph with 4 nodes and 2 edges:

```
1 —— 2
|
3    4
```

There are 4 non-edges to choose from: (1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4). Using either Maria's or Philip's method of randomly choosing the first vertex from all 4 vertices and then choosing the second vertex from the restricted set of vertices so as not to create any edges (or self-loops) will give the following probabilities for each non-edge to be chosen:

p(1,4) = 1/4 * 1 + 1/4 * 1/3 = 8/24

p(2,3) = 1/4 * 1/2 + 1/4 * 1/2 = 6/24

p(3,4) = p(2,4) = 1/4 * 1/2 + 1/4 * 1/3 = 5/24

So the procedure is not uniform.

That means if you want uniformly sampled non-edges, you will have to choose both vertices unrestricted and reject the sample (both vertices) whenever they form an existing edge (or are equal). In NetworkX:

```
v1 = np.random.choice(G.nodes())
v2 = np.random.choice(G.nodes())

while G.has(edge(v1,v2)) or v1==v2:
  v1 = np.random.choice(G.nodes())
  v2 = np.random.choice(G.nodes())
```

Comment: This solution is not very efficient, consider a graph with all but one edge already existing, this could lead to extremely long compute time. Is there an efficient method of solving this? The only solution I came up with is just listing all non-existing edges and choosing a random one, however this results in O(N^2) complexity.

Comment: You are correct, a more effective way would be to make a list of non-edges first. Given an existing network, this can be done efficiently by constructing the Cartesian product of the number of nodes with itself (minus self-links (v,v) and half of symmetric links (v,u),(u,v)) and then take the set difference of that product with the existing edges.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that library, but I'd guess you could do the following:

```
  n1 = random.choice(g.nodes())
  n2 = random.choice(g.nodes()) 
  while (n1 == n2 or any of the edges of n1 lead to n2):
    n2 = random.choice(g.nodes())
  enjoy(yourNodes)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If the graph is small, you can collect `nx.non_edges()` into an `np.array` and `random.choice` from it:

```
non_edges = np.array(nx.non_edges(graph))

sample_num = 10000
sample = non_edges[np.random.choice(len(non_edges), sample_num, replace=False)]
```

Beware that `non_edges()` itself returns you the generator, not the actual list. But if you turn it into an `np.array` you acutally collects all the items in the generator. If your graph is large and sparse, this may raise a memory error, but for small graphs it would the most straightforward way to do it.