# g.nodes() from networkx is not working with random.choice()

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to generate random edges between random nodes but the line of code `ab=choice(G.nodes())` is generating errors.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import choice
G=nx.Graph()
city_set=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
for each in city_set:
    G.add_node(each)
ab=choice(G.nodes())
print(ab)
```

Errors

> C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda2\envs\untitled\python.exe
>   C:/Users/DELL/Documents/PythonPrograms/Beginning/ntwxproject.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/PythonPrograms/Beginning/ntwxproject.py",
>   line 10, in 
>          ab=choice(G.nodes())
>        File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda2\envs\untitled\lib\random.py", line 259, in choice
>       return seq[i]   File "C:\Users\DELL\Anaconda2\envs\untitled\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\reportviews.py",
>   line 178, in **getitem**
>        return self._nodes[n] KeyError: 1
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I'm new to python, help me with it.

Comment: we will need more of the code to help, especially it's unclear wht G.nodes() is()

Comment: list of all the nodes of the Graph G
anyway here's the code



`import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import choice
G=nx.Graph()
city_set=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
for each in city_set:
    G.add_node(each)
ab=choice(G.nodes())
print(ab)`

Comment: and what is `choice()`? `random.choice()`? Can you show the code block where G.nodes() is defined? Questions should always contain a minimal example illustrating the problem - which means we should be able to copy-paste it to our dev-environment and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @OBu i've edited the question and added the whole code, sorry first time posting

Comment: np - I just updated my answer and added an example for creating the edges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not 100% clear what you want to do next, I try to give some hints on how to use `random.choice()` in combination with your city list (please note it's a "list", not a "set" - a better identifyer would be city_list).

Edit: I see you added some information - so I added a way to build the edges...

Your main problem is, that `G.nodes()` is a `<class 'networkx.classes.reportviews.NodeView'>`and not a simple list (even though its string representation looks like a list).

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import random 

G=nx.Graph() 
city_list=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

# this is a bit easier then adding each node in a loop 
G.add_nodes_from(city_list)

# show type and content of G.nodes() 
print(G.nodes())
print(type(G.nodes()))

# based on your old code:    
for _ in city_list: 
    ab=random.choice(city_list) 
    print(ab)
print("list is now", city_list)

# generate n random edges
n=5
for _ in range(n):
    # random.sample(city_list, 2) gives a 2-tuple from city list
    # The '*'-operator unpacks the tuple to two input values for the .add_edge() method
    G.add_edge(*random.sample(city_list, 2))
print("Edges generated:", G.edges())
```

I hope this helps a bit...

Comment: Thank you, it certainly helped alot

Comment: If it helped, an upvote is appreciated. If it solves your problem, "accepting" the answer would be nice. And have fun on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4):

You can convert G.nodes() into a list format compatible with random.choice() by passing list(G.nodes()) instead of just G.nodes().

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from random import choice      
G=nx.Graph()      
city_set=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'] 
for each in city_set:     
    G.add_node(each)     
ab= choice(list(G.nodes())) 
print(ab)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Please support your answer with some code and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

G.node usage is replaced by G.nodes from networkx version 2.4.

Hence you might come across this error if you are trying to un an old code which uses G.node as a key(s) identifier.

Replace all G.node with G.nodes or vice versa. depending on teh  version you are trying to work.

[image]